# Why is a trait needed in order to constrain the type parameter?

Tags: rust

Why is the trait needed in the following code? The commented variant without a trait does not compile, even if it looks as if it has the same information available.

```
trait ReliabilityConstructor<T> {
    fn new(a: T) -> Reliability;
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Debug)]
struct Reliability {
    alpha: i8,
}

//impl<T> Reliability
impl<T> ReliabilityConstructor<T> for Reliability
where
    f64: std::convert::From<T>,
{
    fn new(a: T) -> Reliability {
        let mut a_f64 = f64::from(a);
        a_f64 = if a_f64 < -1f64 {
            -1f64
        } else if a_f64 > 1f64 {
            1f64
        } else {
            a_f64
        };
        Reliability {
            alpha: (100f64 * a_f64) as i8,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Reliability::new(-1));
}
```

When the commented line is uncommented:

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `T` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/main.rs:10:6
   |
10 | impl<T> Reliability
   |      ^ unconstrained type parameter
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the trait from `From` to [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) (because `From<T> for U` implies `Into<U> for T`) - the intention is much more clear:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Debug)]
struct Reliability {
    alpha: i8,
}

impl Reliability {
    fn new<T: Into<f64>>(a: T) -> Reliability { // <T> is only here
        let mut a_f64: f64 = a.into(); // into() is used here
        a_f64 = if a_f64 < -1f64 {
            -1f64
        } else if a_f64 > 1f64 {
            1f64
        } else {
            a_f64
        };
        Reliability { alpha: (100f64 * a_f64) as i8 }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Reliability::new(-1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that certainly becomes more readable and gets rid of the trait. I suppose that also means Reliability to implement Into, which is a nice touch :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have the type parameter defined on the trait definition, not the struct definition. To get rid of the trait, you'll need to move `T` onto the struct itself:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Debug)]
struct Reliability<T> {
    alpha: i8,
}

impl<T> Reliability<T>
where
    f64: std::convert::From<T>,
{
    fn new(a: T) -> Reliability<T> {
        let mut a_f64 = f64::from(a);
        a_f64 = if a_f64 < -1f64 {
            -1f64
        } else if a_f64 > 1f64 {
            1f64
        } else {
            a_f64
        };
        Reliability {
            alpha: (100f64 * a_f64) as i8,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Reliability::new(-1));
}
```

That said, this raises a different issue - `Reliability` doesn't actually use `T` anywhere in the definition or implementation, so it'll fall over with this error:

```
error[E0392]: parameter `T` is never used
 --> src/main.rs:2:20
  |
2 | struct Reliability<T> {
  |                    ^ unused type parameter
  |
  = help: consider removing `T` or using a marker such as `std::marker::PhantomData`
```

Your issue is that you're not trying to constrain the struct, you're just trying to constrain the method. In which case, it's much easier!

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Debug)]
struct Reliability {
    alpha: i8,
}

impl Reliability {
    fn new<T>(a: T) -> Reliability
    where
        f64: std::convert::From<T>,
    {
        let mut a_f64 = f64::from(a);
        a_f64 = if a_f64 < -1f64 {
            -1f64
        } else if a_f64 > 1f64 {
            1f64
        } else {
            a_f64
        };
        Reliability {
            alpha: (100f64 * a_f64) as i8,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Reliability::new(-1));
}
```